# change sign up with e-mail to sign up with username orionjs

Tags: meteor

How can I change sign up with e-mail to sign up with username in orionjs?
For example it is possible to change when you use user:accounts. Just adding

Accounts.ui.config({
  passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_ONLY'
});

For orionjs what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Since the orionjs CMS system does not use the accounts-ui package it is not possible to use this parameter to change the way people sign up.

You would have to fork the project and edit out the code to your preferences.

The code can be found here but it is not at easy as it may seem changing an a line or two since emails are tightly integrated with the CMS:

https://github.com/orionjs/orion/tree/master/packages/bootstrap/views/accounts